# Align error: ! Missing } inserted. l.75 \end {align}

Tags: equations, errors, align, alignment

I'm just picking up LaTeX and I'm having trouble with align. Here's the offending code:

```
\begin{align}
    A $\lor$ (A $\land$ B) &$\equiv$ $\neg$ $\neg$ (A $\lor$ (A $\land$ B)) \textbf{double negation} \\
\end{align}
```

The error I'm receiving is this:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.75 \end{align}
```

I know that means that I likely need to place a bracket somewhere, but all my bracketed statements are closed. Any ideas?

Comment: align entries are already math, remove all the `$`

Comment: Thank you! Earlier when I was working on a table, I needed those $ to make the logical operators work. Is that because the table entry is not math?

Comment: - Is that because the table entry is not math? - Yes